# What algorithms use fewer comparisons than merge-insertion sort?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

On the Wikipedia page for [Merge-Insertion Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge-insertion_sort#Relation_to_other_comparison_sorts) it says

> Manacher's algorithm and later record-breaking sorting algorithms have all used modifications of the merge-insertion sort ideas.

in reference to sorting algorithms that use the fewest comparisons. But it does not explain what algorithms it's referring to. The page the citation links to also just says "other algorithms".

Comment: You might want to look at TimSort. Also, this question might be better suited to CS StackExchange. https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18536/what-is-a-the-fastest-sorting-algorithm-for-an-array-of-integers

Comment: @AbhinavMathur Ah actually I think that's probably the main answer even if there are more. For some reason I forgot Timsort was based on merge insertion. Thanks!

Comment: I'll echo the comment that this is better suited for CS Stackexchange. Also, as far as I can tell, there is little relation of Timsort with Merge-Insertion sort. Timsort is based on mergesort and insertion sort. However, as the Wiki article and the references point out, Merge-insertion sort is not of much practical interest.

Comment: @kcsquared The question was not about what has practical interest, though it does have practical interest to me. Fair enough if that means it should be on cs though. In terms of relation, M-I is a combinaton of merge and insertion and Timsort is "derived from merge sort and insertion sort". Doing the same task by combining the same solutions in different ways is definitely a relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Other algorithms" doesn't necessarily mean "other practical implementations". M-I is still essentially the theoretical best in terms of comparisons made for an infinite number of elements to sort. That's just as long as you don't have to worry about implementation, memory use, or any other real world concerns.

The other algorithms are improvements to merge insertion rather than completely different concepts. They use small tweaks like changing the order elements are compared or inserting [two elements](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.00849) together more efficiently. [This paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00224-020-09987-4) discusses the worst cases.

[Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) uses similar concepts (specifically in [merging runs](https://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt) of already-sorted data in "galloping mode") but it's more focused on performance in real-world data than asymptotic complexity on infinite random inputs. [Block sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_sort) is another fancy algorithm that actually sorts in-place but I don't have a comparison count at the moment. It's implemented in [Wikisort](https://github.com/BonzaiThePenguin/WikiSort) and [Grailsort](https://github.com/HolyGrailSortProject/Rewritten-Grailsort).

For curiosity, here are some worst-case numbers for the merge-insertion variations from the paper linked above:

- `n log n − 1.4427n + O(log n)` - Lowest mathematically possible
- `n log n − 1.3999n + o(n)` - Ford-Johnson Merge-Insertion (original)
- `n log n − 1.4005n + O(n)` - Iwama-Teruyama Merge-Insertion (1,2-insertion)